# RequireJS require.toUrl('../') does not work as I expect

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have my file structure following:

- modules/
- - test_module/
- - - js/
- - - - main.js
- - - view/
- - - - view.html

In requireJs configuration I define my `test_module`.

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "./",
  packages: [
    {
      name: 'test_module',
      location: 'modules/test_module/js'
    }
  ]

});
```

And later i load test_module like:

```
require(['test_module']);
```

The problem is when I try to get url of my view.html from main.js module using `require.toUrl('../view/view.html')`, it returns `'./view/view.html'`, but if I try like this `require.toUrl('./view/view.html')` it returns result as expected `'./modules/test_module/js/view/view.html'`

I created plunker to demonstrate problem I am facing [link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nJFXjJXssCQ1evMotcue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Don't know if it is the best solution, but `require.toUrl('./) + '../view/view.html'` worked fine for me.